# Unable to build react project aws

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, docker, react-native

I am trying to build my project using the AWS pipeline, it was all function correctly yesterday i pushed an update yesterday, since then i have been getting an unsuccessful build. It is a react application using docker container.

I tried reverting the code back to code from previous successful builds however, it still does not build. I run the container on my local machine and everything runs fine.

This is part of the log when it fails

> Creating an optimized production build...
>   Failed to compile.
>
> ./node_modules/@coreui/react/node_modules/reactstrap/es/DropdownToggle.js
>
> Attempted import error: 'Reference' is not exported from 'react-popper'.
>
> ·[91mnpm·[0m·[91m ·[0m·[91mERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> ·[0m·[91mnpm ERR! errno·[0m·[91m 1
>
> ·[0m·[91mnpm ·[0m·[91mERR! compscout-sales@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> ·[0m·[91mnpm ERR!
>
> ·[0m·[91mnpm ERR! Failed at the compscout-sales@0.1.0 build script.
>
> npm ·[0m·[91mERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> ·[0m·[91m
>
> ·[0m·[91mnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!·[0m·[91m     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-08-03T02_48_42_802Z-debug.log
>
> ·[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=$REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 1
>
> make: *** [publish-app] Error 1
>
> [Container] 2019/08/03 02:48:48 Command did not exit successfully make publish-app exit status 2
>
> [Container] 2019/08/03 02:48:48 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
>
> [Container] 2019/08/03 02:48:48 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: make publish-app. Reason: exit status 2

```
 "reactstrap": { 
  "version": "7.1.0", 
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/reactstrap/-/reactstrap-7.1.0.tgz", 
  "integrity": "sha512-wtc4RkgnGn1TsZ0AxOZ2OqT+b8YmCWZj/tErPujWLepxzlEEhveZGC+uDerdaHVSAzJUP2DTk605iper7hutQQ==", 
  "requires": { 
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.2.0", 
    "classnames": "^2.2.3", 
    "lodash.isfunction": "^3.0.9", 
    "lodash.isobject": "^3.0.2", 
    "lodash.tonumber": "^4.0.3", 
    "prop-types": "^15.5.8", 
    "react-lifecycles-compat": "^3.0.4", 
    "react-popper": "^0.10.4", 
    "react-transition-group": "^2.3.1" 
  } 
}, 

"react-popper": { 
  "version": "0.10.4", 
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-popper/-/react-popper-0.10.4.tgz", 
  "integrity": "sha1-rypBXqIike3VBGeNev2opu4ylao=", 
  "requires": { 
    "popper.js": "^1.14.1", 
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1" 
  } 
},
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "myReactProjecr",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@coreui/coreui": "^2.1.7",
    "@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips": "^1.2.0",
    "@coreui/icons": "0.3.0",
    "@coreui/react": "^2.1.5",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-less": "^3.3.8",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.10.0",
    "exceljs": "^0.8.2",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "express-rate-limit": "^3.5.1",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.3.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "pg-promise": "^8.6.5",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "ramda": "^0.26.1",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-apollo": "^2.5.6",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^0.2.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.7.4",
    "react-cookie": "^4.0.0",
    "react-dates": "^20.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-js-pagination": "^3.0.2",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "react-router-config": "^4.4.0-beta.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-select": "^2.4.3",
    "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
    "react-stripe-elements": "^3.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.4",
    "reactstrap": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "sequelize": "^5.8.7",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
    "stripe": "^6.34.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.11.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "start:server": "node ./server/www",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share us your package.json? Some months ago I have similar error with babel npm module. I my case was a  bug in the last release of this module and due to tilde(~) and caret(^) in my package.json for this dependency I got this error.?

Comment: @JRichardsz the package.json is quite large so ive quoted the parts where the react-popper is referenced Thanks

Comment: I think you are shared your package-lock.json. We need at least a part of your package.json to reproduce the error!

Comment: @JRichardsz my bad ive updated it with the package.json it seem i was able to make it compile by deleting my package-lock.json and creating it again however, now i get an error on the site load "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setTargetNode' of undefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working. I had to remove the package-lock.json and deleted my node modules then installed everything again with the new package-lock.json.

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue. Solved it with updating react-popper with its latest version

```
npm install react-popper
```

There's second error related to chalk. I also updated it too

```
npm install chalk
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the reply however, the issue still persists.